# Combining 2 lists like UNION ie keeping 1 copy of mutual items between 2 lists and appending others

Tags: python, list

**I edited it. I made them lists to dictionaries. If a and b are 2 dictionaries:**

```
a = {'UK':'http://www.uk.com', 'COM':['http://www.uk.com','http://www.michaeljackson.com']}



bb = {'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM':['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com','http://www.rogerfederer.com']}
```

I want to union them

```
{'Australia': ['http://www.australia.com'], 'COM': ['http://www.uk.com', 'http://www.michaeljackson.com', 'http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': ['http://www.uk.com']}
```

**I want to union them i.e.**

```
**How to do it in Python without overwwriting and replacing any value?**
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're keeping around a bunch of lists with only 1 element?

Comment: You really want to rethink your data structures, is what I am thinking. Won't a `dict` suit your structure better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a different data structure, such as a dictionary of sets.

```
a = [['UK', ['http://www.uk.com']], ['COM', ['http://www.uk.com'],['http://www.michaeljackson.com']]]
b = [['Australia', ['http://www.australia.com']], ['COM', ['http://www.Australia.com'], ['http://www.rafaelnadal.com'], ['http://www.rogerfederer.com']]]

# convert these to dictionaries with set values
a = {item[0]:set(s[0] for s in item[1:]) for item in a}
b = {item[0]:set(s[0] for s in item[1:]) for item in b}

# define a function to update our dictionary-of-sets data structure
def union_update_setdict(D, *setdicts):
    """Update dictionary D (with `'key':set(value)` items) with items from setdicts.

    If a new key is added to D from setdicts, a shallow copy of the value
    is added to D.
    """
    for setdict in setdicts:
        for k,v in setdict.items():
            try:
                D[k].update(v)
            except KeyError:
                D[k] = v.copy()

union_update_setdict(a, b)



# Now let's test that the code works

expected = [['UK', ['http://www.uk.com']], ['COM', ['http://www.uk.com'], ['http://www.michaeljackson.com'], ['http://www.Australia.com'], ['http://www.rafaelnadal.com'], ['http://www.rogerfederer.com']], ['Australia', ['http://www.australia.com']]]

# put the "expected" results in our new data structure for comparison
expected = {item[0]:set(s[0] for s in item[1:]) for item in expected}

print a
assert expected == a
```

If you really need to keep using your terrible data structure, you can convert it back when you are finished:

```
terribledatastruct = [[k]+[[item] for item in v] for k,v in a.items()]
print terribledatastruct
```

Comment: I am new to Python, Thanks for making me learn and know about dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe a `defaultdict` could be helpful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [['UK', ['http://www.uk.com']], ['COM', ['http://www.uk.com'],['http://www.michaeljackson.com']]]

b = [['Australia', ['http://www.australia.com']], ['COM', ['http://www.Australia.com'], ['http://www.rafaelnadal.com'], ['http://www.rogerfederer.com']]]

d = defaultdict(list)
d.update((v[0],v[1:]) for v in a)
for v in b:
    country_or_com = v[0]
    urls = v[1:]
    d[country_or_com].extend(urls)
```

This isn't exactly the data-structure you ask for, but it's pretty close (and I think prefereble).

If you really want it in the format you have (although in a different order):

```
c = []
for k,v in d.items():
   out = [k]
   out.extend(v)
   c.append(out)
```

results in:

```
[['Australia', ['http://www.australia.com']],
 ['COM', ['http://www.uk.com'], ['http://www.michaeljackson.com'],['http://www.Australia.com'], ['http://www.rafaelnadal.com'], ['http://www.rogerfederer.com']],
 ['UK', ['http://www.uk.com']]]
```

As desired.

Comment: I think, as an example at least, unpacking each b in to named variables in each loop iteration would be clearer.

Comment: @sr2222 -- maybe.  But I don't know what to name them.  `country_or_com` and `urls` maybe?  Honestly, this data structure makes almost no sense to me... In any event, I've updated.

Comment: Why don't you add code at the end to convert it to the desired result?

Comment: @martineau -- I've added it.  But the data structure is pretty strange, so there's no clean way to do it ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know about python

Answer (score 1):

if your lists are dictionaries you just need to merge the dictionaries:

```
>>> a = {'UK':'http://www.uk.com', 'COM':['http://www.uk.com','http://www.michaeljackson.com']}
>>> bb = {'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM':['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com','http://www.rogerfederer.com']}
>>> dict(a.items()+bb.items())
{'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM': ['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': 'http://www.uk.com'}
```

### update

my answer so far does that:

```
>>> sk = list(set(bb.keys()+a.keys()))
>>> sk
['Australia', 'COM', 'UK']
>>> nd
{}

>>> for i in sk: 
...     if i in a.keys():
...        nd[i]=a[i]
... 
>>> nd
{'COM': ['http://www.uk.com', 'http://www.michaeljackson.com'], 'UK': 'http://www.uk.com'}
>>> for i in sk: 
...     if i in bb.keys():
...        nd[i]=bb[i]
... 
>>> nd
{'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM': ['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': 'http://www.uk.com'}
```

I suspect one should still use dictionaries, here is a not very cpu efficient* way to do it:

```
a = {'UK':'http://www.uk.com', 'COM':['http://www.uk.com','http://www.michaeljackson.com']}
bb = {'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM':['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com','http://www.rogerfederer.com']}

sk = list(set(bb.keys()+a.keys()))

nd = {}

for i in sk:
    plholder=[]
    if i in a.keys():
        print i
        print isinstance(a[i], str)
        if isinstance(a[i], str):
            plholder.append(a[i])
        else:
            if i in a.keys():
                for v in a[i]: plholder.append(v)
    if i in bb.keys():
        if isinstance(bb[i], str): plholder.append(bb[i])
        else:
            if i in a.keys():
                for v in bb[i]: plholder.append(v)
    nd[i]=plholder
print nd
{'Australia': ['http://www.australia.com'], 'COM': ['http://www.uk.com', 'http://www.michaeljackson.com', 'http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': ['http://www.uk.com']}
```

*non cpu efficient because for large data sets append will be very slow.

Comment: In your merge here, `'COM'` losses `'http://www.michaeljackson.com'`.  In other words, you don't *merge*, you *overwrite*.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work in python3 because `dict.items()` returns a iterator, not a list. (`a.items()+b.items()` will fail).

Comment: @ManabChetia, I just posted up how you can prevent overwrite, look at my latest code.

Answer (score 1):

Strange data structures are often to suit some strange devilish library lurking below.  I'd propose, for obviousness's sake, to transform that into proper data structures, work with those, then transform it back.  You avoid implementation trouble with a hand-knitted union algorithm on your strange structure etc.

First, make the data decent:

```
a_ = { x[0]: set(e[0] for e in x[1:]) for x in a }
b_ = { x[0]: set(e[0] for e in x[1:]) for x in b }
```

Then work with it:

```
c_ = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in a_.iteritems():
    c_[k] |= v
for k, v in b_.iteritems():
    c_[k] |= v
```

Then transform it back to your strange structure:

```
return [[k] + [[e] for e in v] for k, v in c_.iteritems()]
```

This way I think what is really done is clear.

Assumptions:  I assume (1) that sorting orders are not important and (2) that values appear only once.  If some of this is not true, please state so.  Your question was so brief I had to do some interpretation.

for people who are not familiar with `sets` unique short cuts:
`c_[k] |= v,` can be written as:
`c_[k] = c_[k].union(v)`.

see [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html)

Comment: Thanks Oz123.  I really weep for the lack of unicode operators like ∪ in Python …