# Python Merge 2 Dictionaries without overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary

If a and b are 2 dictionaries:

```
a = {'UK':'http://www.uk.com', 'COM':['http://www.uk.com','http://www.michaeljackson.com']}



bb = {'Australia': 'http://www.australia.com', 'COM':['http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com','http://www.rogerfederer.com']}
```

I want to merge them to get

```
{'Australia': ['http://www.australia.com'], 'COM': ['http://www.uk.com', 'http://www.michaeljackson.com', 'http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': ['http://www.uk.com']}
```

I want to union them i.e.

**How to do it in Python without overwwriting and replacing any value?**

Comment: overwriting means? it will overwrite key with same name.

Comment: I dont want to overwrite

Answer (score 3):

Use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d  = defaultdict(list)

for dd in (a,bb):
    for k,v in dd.items():
        #Added this check to make extending work for cases where 
        #the value is a string.
        v = (v,) if isinstance(v,basestring) else v  #basestring is just str in py3k.
        d[k].extend(v)
```

(but this is pretty much what I told you in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12389519/748858))

This now works if your input dictionaries look like

```
{'Australia':['http://www.australia.com']}
```

or like:

```
{'Australia':'http://www.australia.com'}
```

However, I would advise against the latter form.  In general, I think it's a good idea to keep all the keys/values of a dictionary looking the same (at least if you want to treat all the items the same as in this question).  That means that if one value is a list, it's a good idea for *all of them* to be a list.

If you really insist on keeping things this way:

```
d = {}
for dd in (a,b):
   for k,v in dd.items():
       if(not isinstance(v,list)):
          v = [v]
       try:
          d[k].extend(v)
       except KeyError: #no key, no problem, just add it to the dict.
          d[k] = v
```

Comment: I get this result `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Australia': ['h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'w', 'w', 'w', '.', 'a', 'u', 's', 't', 'r', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'a', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm'], 'COM': ['http://www.uk.com', 'http://www.michaeljackson.com', 'http://www.Australia.com', 'http://www.rafaelnadal.com', 'http://www.rogerfederer.com'], 'UK': ['h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'w', 'w', 'w', '.', 'u', 'k', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm']})`

Comment: @ManabChetia -- Yeah, that's what I expected to happen -- I can add a check to get around that ...

Comment: It will be really helpful if you show me how to get the exact output

Comment: @ManabChetia -- See my updated `defaultdict` example.  It should give you what you want.

Comment: @mgilson: `isinstance` typo on v2.

Comment: @DSM -- Always type that one wrong (maybe because I try not to type it often).

Comment: @mgilson Can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572225/python-multiword-index/12572417#12572417