# Python Multiword Index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
index = {'Michael': [['mj.com',1], ['Nine.com',9],['i.com', 34]], / 
         'Jackson': [['One.com',4],['mj.com', 2],['Nine.com', 10], ['i.com', 45]], /
         'Thriller' : [['Seven.com', 7], ['Ten.com',10], ['One.com', 5], ['mj.com',3]}

# In this dictionary (index), for eg: 'KEYWORD': 
# [['THE LINK in which KEYWORD is present,'POSITION
# of KEYWORD in the page specified by link']]
```

> eg: Michael is present in MJ.com, NINE.com, and i.com at positions 1, 9, 34 of respective pages.

Please help me with a python procedure which takes `index` and `KEYWORDS` as input.

When i enter `'MICHAEL'`. The result should be:

```
>>['mj.com', 'nine.com', 'i.com']
```

When I enter `'MICHAEL JACKSON'.` The result should be :

`>>['mj.com', 'Nine.com']`

as '`Michael'` and '`Jackson'` are present at `'mj.com'` and `'nine.com'` consecutively i.e. in positions (1,2) & (9,10) respectively. The result should not show `'i.com'` even though it contains both KEYWORDS but they are not placed consecutively.

When I enter `'MICHAEL JACKSON THRILLER',` the result should be

`['mj.com']`

as the 3 words `'MICHAEL', 'JACKSON', 'THRILLER'` are placed consecutively in `'mj.com'` ie positions (1, 2, 3) respectively.

If I enter `'THRILLER JACKSON'` or `'THRILLER FEDERER',` the result should be `NONE`.

Comment: I am trying to build a multiword search engine.

Comment: are you using a DB? is this for real life or school ? If it is for real life you probably want to rethink your design...

Comment: Its not real life. I am just trying some 2 or 3 pages.

Comment: so its for school? ... there is little academic value in this excersize other than figuring out how to manipulate/parse dictionaries ...

Comment: how is KEYWORDS defined?

Comment: also why wouldnt `'MICHAEL'` include `'i.com'`

Comment: for `Michael` the answer should be `['mj.com', 'Nine.com','i.com']`?

Comment: Sorry Michael would include i.com

Comment: @Jordan Beasley: I am trying on my own. It ain't any school or college work. :), But not able to do it.

Comment: @selllikesybok Keywords are string. We can use Keywords.split() to take individual keywords

Comment: What if a word appears more than one time on a site?

Comment: @ManabChetia I think you should use something like : `{'Michael': {'mj.com':1,'Nine.com':9,'i.com':34},
         'Jackson':{'One.com':4,'mj.com':2,'Nine.com':10,'i.com':45},
         'Thriller' : {'Seven.com':7,'Ten.com':10,'One.com':5,'mj.com':3}}`

Comment: @tobias_k I have another function which takes care of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note, Udacity Intro to CS covers precisely this question. This makes a number of assumptions about proper inputs (essentially that it never encounters any incorrect ones).

```
def lookup(index,KEYWORDS):
    kw = KEYWORDS.split()
    if len(kw) == 1:
        return [site[0] for site in index[kw[0]]]
    else:
        positions = {}
        result = []
        kw = KEYWORDS.split()
        for kword in kw:
            for site in index[kword]:
                positions[(kword,site[0])]=site[1]
        for i in range(0,len(kw)-1):
            cur_urls = [site[0] for site in index[kw[i]]]
            next_urls = [site[0] for site in index[kw[i+1]]]
            if i == 0:
                result = cur_urls
            for url in cur_urls:
                if url in next_urls:
                    if not (positions[kw[i+1],url]-positions[kw[i],url]) == 1:
                        result.remove(url)
                else:
                    if url in result:
                        result.remove(url)
        return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I did intro to CS from udacity and happy that you recognized my problem.

Comment: Had an error in my suggestion, so fixed it. You would need to fix this to handle situations where a search term in a phrase is not a dictionary key - that will create an error in my suggested code.

Comment: No, I haven't used that one before. I will check it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

using sets and intersection:

```
def func(key,dic):
    keys=key.split()
    values=[set(y if i==0 else y if dic[x][y]-dic[keys[i-1]].get(y,-10000)==1 \
                else None for y in dic[x]) for i,x in enumerate(keys)]
    sett=values[0]
    for y in values[1:]:
        sett &= y
    print(sett)

index = {'Michael': {'mj.com':1,'Nine.com':9,'i.com':34},
         'Jackson':{'One.com':4,'mj.com':2,'Nine.com':10,'i.com':45},
         'Thriller' : {'Seven.com':7,'Ten.com':10,'One.com':5,'mj.com':3}}
```

**output:**

```
>>> func("Michael",index)
{'Nine.com', 'mj.com', 'i.com'}
>>> func("Michael Jackson",index)
{'Nine.com', 'mj.com'}
>>> func("Michael Jackson Thriller",index)
{'mj.com'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help!! :) But the result is showing i.com wch is not reqd for MICHAEL JACKSON as MICHAEL and JACKSON are not consecutively placed at i.com

Comment: @ManabChetia solution edited, I think instead of using a list of lists you should probably use a dictionary of dictionary. It's a more appropriate data-structure here.

Comment: You are a mighty programmer. Thanks a lot for your help. But ain't it possible to use list only, as I have to change many other functions in my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @ManabChetia I tried my best to do it with list of lists, but failed :) But,I suggest you to use appropriate data-structures, so changing some code will surely help you.

Comment: A way to do this for phrases is to create a companion dictionary with (keyword, site) tuples as keys and positions as records.

Comment: @selllikesybok but that will require some extra memory in case `index` becomes huge.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - sometimes 'go redesign the rest of your program' isn't an option. Sometimes it is. Different solutions for different scenarios. I proposed a solution to the question asked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, since your search seems to ignore case, you should uppercase (or lowercase) your index.

```
index = dict((key.upper(), val) for (key, val) in index.iteritems())
```

Now here is a recursive approach. First, the interface function:

```
def search(query):
    return [site for (site, pos) in search2(query.split())]
```

The next function does the actual work. If only one word is given, return the entry in the index for this word; otherwise filter for those indices where the positions match up.

```
def search2(words):
    if len(words) == 1:
        return index[words[0]]
    else:
        return [(site1, pos1) for (site1, pos1) in index[words[0]]
                              for (site2, pos2) in search2(words[1:])
                              if (site1 == site2 and pos1 == pos2-1)]
```

Of course, things get a little more complicated if `pos` can actually be a *list* of positions for each site...

Comment: THanks a lot. Do you know to use whoosh?